# how to get the path of a localized plist under mac os x

Tags: macos

i have a plist placed inside en.lproj. I am trying to get its path this way,

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSMutableString *localizedPath = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@/%@",bundlePath,lang,@"lproj",@"1.plist"];
```

where 1.plist is in en.lproj/1.plist put in resources.

Does `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];` give correct path to my resources? Can any body give me any clue. I am using this for iPhone , and i am new to Mac os x development, can it be used for mac os x development as well?

--
Regards,

U'suf

Answer (score 2):

It get the path to the resources directory, use

```
NSString * resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
```

To get the path to a particular resource though use

```
NSString * resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"plist"];
```

The above will get the resource from the localization declared by the user in their general settings.

If you want to specify the localization yourself, then try

```
NSString * resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"plist" inDirectory:nil forLocalization:localization];
```

Comment: Hey yes i was missing the path for resources. thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `-pathForResource:ofType:`